# What unblocked ports are necessary for github to work?

Tags: ssh, git, github

My work has blocked github. Attempting to pull from a github repo produces this message:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

Does this mean only port 22 needs to be unblocked? Or should more be unblocked? They have told me that if I provide the instructions, they will unblock github.

Comment: That error message alone is sufficient for competent IT staff to figure out what needs to be unblocked. They should not be making the developers do their jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to unblock port 22.

Since you are in an network check that you have the right [proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy) settings. (and git uses them)

Also see that you can resolve `github.com` (`ping github.com`)